# Вопрос по js, как достать нужное число?

Tags: javascript

Получаю с сервера числа в стиле `"33979.98"`
Мне необходимо получить только `979.98.` т.е первые 2 символа не нужны, как не нужны и все последующие после `98.` Чет не могу сообразить, как их получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log(
  "33979.98".match(/.{3}\..{2}/)?.slice(0,1)[0]
)
```

Comment: Вау) Спасибо. Правда несколько запутанно, не пойму почему так)